# intent putextra does not working on adapter

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android programming.
I get a problem when I want to send the data to the intent putextra to new activity in my listview adapter.
This code my adapter

```
    package com.app.amusa.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.app.amusa.FragOrangtua;
import com.app.amusa.R;
import com.app.amusa.ViewDetailAnak;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FroListAnakAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Anak> AnakList;
    private String id_anak;

    public FroListA

nakAdapter(Activity activity, List<Anak> AnakList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.AnakList = AnakList;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return AnakList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return AnakList.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_anak, null);
    TextView nama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
    TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    TextView anak_ke = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.anak_ke);

    final Anak a = AnakList.get(position);

    nama.setText(a.getnama());
    username.setText(a.getusername());
    anak_ke.setText("Anak Ke : " + String.valueOf(a.getanak_ke()));
    final int idanak = a.getid_anak();

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewDetailAnak.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_anak",String.valueOf(idanak));
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(intent));

        }
    });
    return convertView;
    }

}
```

and here is ViewDetailAnak Oncreate

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_item_anak);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    streamer = new Streamer();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    idanak = i.getStringExtra("id_anak");
    //id
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idanak, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Asyncronous().execute();
}
```

for nama, username, and anak_ke, the value of successfully filled in TextView.
perhaps also in idanak successfully filled idanak.
but when in ViewDetailAnak. The idanak returns 0
and I tried to change the value idanak with getanak_ke ()
but the value remains 0 when the value of getanak_ke is 1

if I had to put it in the main activity? if yes, how?
or whether there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: probably last listview row item `idanak` value is zero ?

Comment: make sure your idanak is actually non-zero. Log it before you put it in extras

Comment: Probably not the solution but why do you need an additional new Intent for an intent you've just created?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its impossible because idanak is primary key on my database and value is 1. and i've try to show on textview and value is 1. just on intent the value is zero.

Comment: @Kasra i've try to show on textview and value is 1. just on intent the value is zero.

Comment: @riskywidiantoro: how many rows currently in ListView?

Comment: @mikepenz hmm i just try make an additional new intent, i hope that can solve my prob, but the result is the same.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK just 2 rows

Comment: @riskywidiantoro: so what is value of  `idanak` for last row?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting last row value of `idanak` because when `getView` method called for creating ListView rows then `idanak` only hold value which is assigned on last call of getView method.

To get value according to row click use `setTag-getTag` methods as:

```
convertView.setTag(idanak);
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int id_idanak=Integer.parseInteger(arg0.getTag().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewDetailAnak.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_anak",String.valueOf(id_idanak));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the problem has been resolved. I just panicked and did not look into the code for connection to the server, especially for idanak. so the value idanak not set in json. thank you for reminding me to check the value idanak.

Comment: @riskywidiantoro: Good if issue fixed but without use of setTag/getTag you will not get right value of idanak for clicked row . Thanks